# Spring boot, JWT and angular not working : HTTP status code 403 error for method put

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, http, spring-security

I  am  new  to  angular  and  spring-security.  I am  having  problem  with  updating  my  data  from  angular  but  i  can update  it  using  insomnia  when  i  test  my  api  (i pass  the  token  in  the  header).

Im  passing  the  token  to  the  put   method  but  i  get  access denied  403

this  is  my  function  in  angular  service

```
  private headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization':  this.authService.jwt
    });
updateUserById(id: String): Observable<any> {
    console.log(this.headers);

    return this.http.put(this.host_3 + '/' + id, {headers: this.headers});
  }
```

this  is  my  function  in  component  controller

```
onSubmit(){
   this.updateCustomer();
  }
  updateCustomer(){
    console.log("inside update"+this.userr);
    this.coordservice.updateUserById(this.userr).
    subscribe(data => console.log("data"+data), error => console.log(error));
  }
```

this  is  my  backend  function  in  spring  controller

```
 @PutMapping(value = "/customersList/updateCustomer/{idCustomer}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> update(@PathVariable(name = "idCustomer") String idCustomer, @RequestBody Customer customer){
        this.customerService.updateCustomer(idCustomer,customer);
        return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(customer, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

Security configuration

```
rotected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH");
```

Note:  i  can  get  data  using  http.get()  but  for  method   put  i  get  access denied

Comment: Might be blocked due to CORS preflight, you can try first adding OPTIONS in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods: response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"); - Would be useful if you edited the question with the response headers

Comment: Seems like a XSRF protection from Spring security.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to add *OPTIONS* methods as an allowed method as following

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH");
```

For CORS, the browser will send the OPTIONS request to verify that it is making a request to correct the server, (known as prefight requests) if it will be successfully responded actual request is initiated.

---

CSRF token also plays an important role in security. You may have to configure it according to your requirements

To disable you may use `.csrf().disable()` as following

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public-api-such-as-login").permitAll() 
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

If you want to include the CSRF you may use `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` as follows. You may also like to explore [how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62393739/10961238)

```
http
            .csrf()
            .ignoringAntMatchers("endpoint-to-be-ignored-for-csrf")
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public-api-such-as-login").permitAll() 
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
```